# Data from the instagram clone android application are not reflecting at the realtime database in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a clone of Instagram application in Android Studio. So, I want to store all the data of users from the clone application to the realtime database in firebase. I have also created one realtime database(Test database) in Firebase and set the FirebaseDatabase dependency in my application. The problem is when I'm entering the data from my registration page and click on the register button, it was perfectly authenticating the data in Firebase but nothing is reflecting on the realtime database. Any suggestions will be perfect for me. Below, I'm sharing my codes following to this problem:

**RegistrationActivity.java**

```
package com.shankhadeep.firebaseinstagram;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "TAG";
    EditText username, fullname, email, password;
    Button btn_register;
    TextView txt_login;
    DatabaseReference mRootRef;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
//    FirebaseFirestore fStore;


    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        fullname = findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        btn_register = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        txt_login = findViewById(R.id.txt_login);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);

        mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
//        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


        txt_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Registration.this,Login.class));
            }
        });

        btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String textUserName = username.getText().toString();
                String textFullName = fullname.getText().toString();
                String emailId = email.getText().toString();
                String txt_Password = password.getText().toString();


                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(textUserName) || TextUtils.isEmpty(textFullName) || TextUtils.isEmpty(emailId) || TextUtils.isEmpty(txt_Password)){
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"Empty credentials", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else if(txt_Password.length() < 6) {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Password too short!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else {
                    registerUser(textUserName, textFullName, emailId, txt_Password);
                    startActivity(new Intent(Registration.this,Login.class));
                    finish();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void registerUser(final String textUserName, final String textFullName, final String emailId, final String txt_password) {
        pd.setMessage("Please Wait!");
        pd.show();

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailId , txt_password).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {

                HashMap<String , Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("name" , textUserName);
                map.put("email", emailId);
                map.put("username" , username);
                map.put("id" , auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                map.put("bio" , "");
                map.put("imageurl" , "default");

                mRootRef.child("Users").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Update the profile " +
                                    "for better expereince", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Registration.this , MainActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                pd.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(Registration.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**build.gradle(app level)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shankhadeep.firebaseinstagram"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation "com.hendraanggrian.appcompat:socialview:0.2"
    implementation "com.hendraanggrian.appcompat:socialview-commons:0.2"
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'

    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

**Here are some snapshots**

[Database creation and rules setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Id0.png)

[Registration page in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk53o.png)

[Data entered and registering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXqtz.png)

[Autthentication successfull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzxm2.png)

[Empty realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxf6m.png)

Comment: Is your `onComplete()` even triggered?

Comment: Yes! It was printing the Toast notification.

Comment: So you that `Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Update the profile " +
                                    "for better expereince", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` works, right? Are you sure you are looking at the correct project?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. The toast was not showing. After the registration it was directly taking me to the dashboard without Loggin in manually since I have added onStart() method in my start activity which will automativally authenticate my information and will redirect me to the dashboard. But yes, the Toast function was not showing after the registration. I am apologising for my last mistake.

Answer (score 0):

first of all get user details if user is exits if not then you should update and if user is exits then update that one accroding to user id